# kurukshetra War

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, rama

Ramayana happened in 24th Treta Yuga whereas Mahabharata happened in 28th dwapara Yuga then how come Shri Ram's Descendant King Brihadbala fought in mahabharat war . Because there is gap of 4 chatur yuga's . How is it possible ?

Comment: Assuming that each Yug has same kinds of kuls like Raghu-Kul, Kauravs, etc., Maybe it could be possible, that "King Brihadbala" is not a direct descendant of Shri Ram (biologically), but a member of the Raghu-Kul (Ishvaku kul) in the 28th Yug, and hence considered as a descendant of Shri Ram.

Comment: Because one of the successor at the end of each Yuga is kept alive by God. Even today King https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devapi of Chandravansha and another king of Suryavansha are alive and meditating in Kalapa Grama of the earth to start Surya and Chandravansha again in next 29th Satyuga. They are mentioned in Kalki Purana in detail.